# SwiftUI Text disappears when presenting ViewController in UIKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

apologies if the title isn't clear enough. I've created a bar chart using SwiftUI and I'm using UIHostingController to add it to my View Controller which is made using UIKit. When I first launch the app all the text shows up and everything seems to work fine, but when I present another View Controller and present the initial View Controller back, the SwiftUI Text doesn't show up, you can only see the bars in the bar chart, check out the video I've added to get a better understanding.

Here's the code for the bar chart, **LineChart.swift**:

```
struct LineChart: View {
    
    let wordsWrittenArray = [40, 80, 150, 90, 75, 180, 50]
    let days = ["Su", "M", "T", "W", "Th", "F", "Sa"]
    let totalWordCount = 400
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Word Count")
                .font(.system(size: 34))
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(Color(Colors.backgroundOppositeColor!))
            
            HStack (spacing: 23) {
                ForEach(0 ..< wordsWrittenArray.count) { index in
                    Bar(wordsWritten: CGFloat(wordsWrittenArray[index]), days: days[index])
                }
            }
            
            Text("\(totalWordCount) Words")
                .font(.system(size: 34))
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(Color(Colors.backgroundOppositeColor!))
                .padding(.top, 15)
        }
    }
}

// Create a struct for the bars
struct Bar: View {
    
    var wordsWritten: CGFloat
    var days: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                
                Capsule().frame(width: 25, height: 180)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(Colors.backgroundOppositeColor!))
                Capsule().frame(width: 25, height: wordsWritten)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(Colors.themeColor!))
            }
            Text(days).padding(.top, 8)
                .foregroundColor(Color(Colors.backgroundOppositeColor!))
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code to where I'm using UIHostingController in the view controller, **MainScreen.swift**:

```
// Setup the SwiftUI Bar Chart View
func setupBarChartView() {
        
    let barChartView = UIHostingController(rootView: LineChart())
    self.addChild(barChartView)
    view.addSubview(barChartView.view)
    barChartView.didMove(toParent: self)
    barChartView.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        
    barChartView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    barChartView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: featuredStoryView.bottomAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    barChartView.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        barChartView.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    barChartView.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: notificationButton.topAnchor, constant: -25).isActive = true
}
```

Here's the video:

[image: Video]

I appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Just a hunch, but it seems the views are still in place, how about testing with changing `.foregroundColor` to something like `Color.red`?

Comment: @EDUsta Yooooo it's working lol, thanks a lot man!!! <3